# Trying to implement a Jetpack Compose Room Query

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I'm fairly new to coding (graduated a program in April) and I'm trying to do a personal project with Jetpack Compose. I essentially have an app where you make a character, and add a selection of spells to that character. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get my @QUERY working as intended. I'm using onEvent to try to get it working in my viewModel as of right now. Even pointing in the right direction to learn how to do it myself is fine. I just can't seem to come up with anything. (This is also my first time posting to stack overflow, sorry if I do something out of normal)

So far this is the last big step to getting my app complete. I have the ability to add/delete characters, see the full list of spells, and passing which character is selected.

In my Dao, my query is:

```
@Query("""SELECT * FROM customlist WHERE characterFk=:characterId AND spellLevel=:spellLevel ORDER BY spellTitle ASC""")
fun getSpellByCharacterAndLevel(characterId:Int, spellLevel:Int):Flow<List<CustomList>>
```

I have it in my event as:

```
sealed interface CustomListEvent {
    class GetSpellByCharacterAndLevel(characterId: Int, spellLevel: Int) : CustomListEvent
}
```

My viewModel, which I'm thinking my problem is mainly coming from:

```
class CustomListViewModel(...):ViewModel() {
    val state = MutableStateFlow(CustomListState())

    fun onEvent(event: CustomListEvent){
        when(event){
            is CustomListEvent.GetSpellByCharacterAndLevel -> {
                val characterId = state.value.characterFk
                val spellLevel = state.value.spellLevel
                dao.getSpellByCharacterAndLevel(characterId, spellLevel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just calling it on my screen is a mess right now, but what I have currently is:

```
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier){
            val levelZeroSpells = listOf( CustomListEvent.GetSpellByCharacterAndLevel(viewModel.characterFkTemp.value,0))
            items(levelZeroSpells){
                Text(text = it.toString())
            }
        }
```

The main idea being that I can separate the list displayed to the user as different spellLevel values.

Comment: Ehm, I am not sure what is the question. Is the question about how to setup UI or is there an issue with how you are fetching data from Room?

Comment: Sorry, fetching the data. I could always just get the full list filtered with an if statement for the level and Fk, but I feel like that's just not a productive way to do it.

Comment: `Flow<List>` What is it the list of?

Comment: Weird, in my code it is "Flow<List<CustomList>>" but that didn't copy over for some reason

Comment: Instead of the what you expect what are you actually getting? It may assist if you edit your question to include the respective `@Entiity` annotated classes (e.g. CustomList). Note to make the code appear as code (edit of your post) paste the code, select the pasted code and click  **`{}`**, the code will the be formatted as code.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind next time I have to post. I'm not really getting anything useful. I've just tried the toString() to see if I could do anything with that was coming out but it was a big no. I've been doing trial and error with it and that's where I ended up before posting. My @Entity is just a data class of CustomList with the val and primary key. I'm going to keep plugging at it later tonight, but I'm just finding it hard to find across some good resources to learn this.